# How to get current page number onPagechange function in react

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am trying to fetch current pageNumber on click next in react table but can not see the current page number.

```
<div className="article_full">
<h2>DETAILS</h2>
<ReactTable filterable columns= . 
{this.getTableColumns()} data={items} pagination={true} onChange={this.onPageChange}/>
</div>

onPageChange(pagination, filters, sorter) {
//projectId = this.props.match.params;
alert(pagination.current)
}
```

Comment: Which version of react-table are you using ? v5 or v6 or v7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the **wrong Controlled State Callbacks** on ReactTable component. Instead of `onChange` try calling `onPageChange`:

```
<div className="article_full">
   <h2>DETAILS</h2>
   <ReactTable 
      filterable 
      columns={this.getTableColumns()} 
      data={items} 
      pagination={true} 
      onPageChange={this.onPageChange}/>
</div>

onPageChange(pageIndex) {
   alert(pageIndex);
}
```

You can test using this [working example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-multiple-pagination-bars-pmd6o?fontsize=14)

## List of possible callbacks

List of possible callbacks based on [react-table documentation](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6):

```
// Callbacks
onPageChange={(pageIndex) => {...}} // Called when the page index is changed by the user
onPageSizeChange={(pageSize, pageIndex) => {...}} // Called when the pageSize is changed by the user. The resolve page is also sent to maintain approximate position in the data
onSortedChange={(newSorted, column, shiftKey) => {...}} // Called when a sortable column header is clicked with the column itself and if the shiftkey was held. If the column is a pivoted column, `column` will be an array of columns
onExpandedChange={(newExpanded, index, event) => {...}} // Called when an expander is clicked. Use this to manage `expanded`
onFilteredChange={(filtered, column) => {...}} // Called when a user enters a value into a filter input field or the value passed to the onFiltersChange handler by the Filter option.
onResizedChange={(newResized, event) => {...}} // Called when a user clicks on a resizing component (the right edge of a column header)
```

Comment: Thanks!!.Instead of alert(pagination.current )only pagination works. alert(pagination.current) is giving undefined.

Comment: My bad, you can only access first parameter as `pageIndex`. Will update accordingly .

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
const handlePageClick = (event) => {
    
    var currentPageCount = event.selected + 1;
    alert(currentPageCount);

};
```

it will return current selected page

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).